# Laravel limit characters

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
href="#0">{{$article->title,}}
```

How do I limit the title to certain characters with "..." at the end?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using twig?

Comment: your question is incomplete, please explain what you want to do!!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-str-limit

Comment: @NaveedAli how could he use jquery in the backend using php?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php

Answer (score 4):

You can use 2 methods to do this:

**Method 1:**

```
 //I am assuming that you need to print first 20 characters from the title
 {{ substr($article->title, 0,  20) }}
```

**Method 2:**

```
 {{ Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($article->title, 20) }}
```

Comment: How about *with "..." at the end*?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel provides a function for this specific usage:

```
{{ Str::limit($article->title, 100, '...') }}
```

`100` is the number of characters to keep,

`...` is the string to append after truncating

Answer (score 1):

You can use substr();
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp

```
{{substr("Hello world",0,25)}}...
```

Comment: How about *with "..." at the end*?

Comment: He said "imit the title to certain characters with "..." at the end". Substr function limit the string then he need just write "..." , thats all.